# Creating a big JSON response from multiples QuerySpec AWS Dynamodb

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have multiples queries using QuerySpec and thus multiples ItemCollection :

```
            Table table4 = dynamoDB.getTable("MyTable"); 
            QuerySpec spec4 = new QuerySpec()
                    .withKeyConditionExpression("id = :v_id")
                    .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .withString(":v_id", SAFETY_CHAPTERS_UUIDS.get(i)));
            ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items4 = table4.query(spec4);
            Iterator<Item> iterator4 = items4.iterator();
            Item itemsQuizzChapters = null;
```

I'am trying to find a way to construct a big JSON response from those 4 Queries.
How i can add the itemCollection to a JSON Object or Object so i can create a big object with all of it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//import aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.85.jar, json-simple-1.1.jar and jackson-all-1.9.9.jar
public JSONObject getItemDynamoDB(String tableName, String primaryKey,String primaryKeyValue) {
       Table index = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
        QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec().withKeyConditionExpression("#primaryKey = :value1")
        .withNameMap(new NameMap().with("#primaryKey", primaryKey))
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":value1", primaryKeyValue));
        ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = index.query(querySpec);
       Iterator<Item> itemIterator = items.iterator();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(itemIterator.next().toJSONPretty());
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return jsonObject;
}
//call the function multiple time to get big JSON

public JSONArray concatenateMultipleItem(){
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray() ;
    jsonArray.add(getItemDynamoDB("TableName", "primaryKey", "1"));
    jsonArray.add(getItemDynamoDB("TableName2", "primaryKey2", "2"));   
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
    return jsonArray;
}
```

[reference](http://www.tryyourskill.com/aws/combine-multiple-dynamodb-queryspec-result-in-a-json)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to query two different tables `Movies` & `post` and return a list of `JSONObject` (i.e. org.json.JSONObject).

Item class has a `toJSON()` to return the item data as Json string. The `toJSON()` method can be used to store the item data as `List<String>` or `List<JSONObject>`.

In the below code sample, I return `List<JSONObject>`.

**Sample code:-**

```
List<JSONObject> resultJson = new ArrayList<>();
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient);

Table tableMovies = dynamoDB.getTable("Movies");
QuerySpec querySpecMovies = new QuerySpec();

querySpecMovies.withKeyConditionExpression("yearkey = :yearval")
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withNumber(":yearval", 2014));

IteratorSupport<Item, QueryOutcome> iterator = tableMovies.query(querySpecMovies).iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Item movieItem = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Movie data ====================>" + movieItem.toJSONPretty());                      
    resultJson.add(new JSONObject(movieItem.toJSON()));
}

Table tablePosts = dynamoDB.getTable("post");
QuerySpec querySpecPosts = new QuerySpec();

querySpecPosts.withKeyConditionExpression("postId = :postIdval")
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withString(":postIdval", "3"));

iterator = tablePosts.query(querySpecPosts).iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Item postItem = iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Post data ====================>" + postItem.toJSONPretty());                        
    resultJson.add(new JSONObject(postItem.toJSON()));
}

return resultJson;
```

**Output:-**

```
[{
    "country": ["IN", "UK", "US"],
    "Description": "Delete and set",
    "yearkey": 2014,
    "total_val": 0,
    "title": "The Big New Movie 2",
    "total_new_val": 2
}, {
    "postId": "3",
    "text": "Hello World",
    "tags": ["A", "C"]
}]
```